# while loop to create an array for a world trip

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, while-loop

I got the below code, where I am trying to output a result of a full trip. The starting point is at `Start`, and the following destination will be the shortest distance between
`Start's` coordinates and one of the remaining cities (it's Toronto in this case).

In my `calcDirectRoute` I've only been able to output `Start` >> `Toronto` trip element, as I am struggling to keep the loop going, where the second element of `TripList` array is the shortest distance between `Toronto` and `London`, let's say, and so on until there's no more city left to go travelling.

How do I keep looping with the while loop in this case? Could someone please help?

Coordinates/distance in km are fictitious in my example.

```js
const world = [
    [["Start"], [20, 20]],
    [["NY"], [29, 30]],
    [["London"], [24, 27]],
    [["Moscow"], [29, 32]],
    [["Toronto"], [20, 23]]
];

const calcDist2Points = function (p2, p1) {
    const r = 6371;
    let d, dLat, dLon;

    const lat2 = p2[1][0];
    const lon2 = p2[1][1];
    const lat1 = p1[1][0];
    const lon1 = p1[1][1];

    dLat = lat2 - lat1;
    dLon = lon2 - lon1;

    let a =
        Math.sin(dLat / 2) ** 2 +
        Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) ** 2;
    let c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    d = r * c;

    return d; // distance in km
};



const calcDirectRoute = function (input) {

    let tripList = [];
    let distances = [];
    let tempStart = input[0];


    for (let i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {

        distances.push([tempStart[0], [tempStart[1][0], tempStart[1][1]], input[i][0], [input[i][1][0], input[i][1][1]], calcDist2Points(input[i], tempStart)]);

    }

    let short = distances[0];

    for (let i = 0; i < distances.length; i++) {
        for (let n = i + 1; n < distances.length; n++) {
            if (distances[n][4] < short[4])
                short = distances[n];
        }
    }

    // push EACH short result to tripList array

    tripList.push(short);


    tempStart = short.slice(2);


    return tripList;

}

console.log(calcDirectRoute(world));
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to visit all the cities, starting from the start till you have covered all the cities, while having the shortest distance possible.

First, you need to figure out every distance from every other city.
then use the Dijkstra algorithm to figure out the path.

Dijkstra Approach : [example](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/shortest-path-visiting-all-nodes#2-implementation-1)

Brute force method:
Here I am making all the valid paths into tree and selected the shortest path.

```js
const world = [
    [
        ["Start"],
        [20, 20]
    ],
    [
        ["NY"],
        [29, 30]
    ],
    [
        ["London"],
        [24, 27]
    ],
    [
        ["Moscow"],
        [29, 32]
    ],
    [
        ["Toronto"],
        [20, 23]
    ]
];

const calcDist2Points = function(p2, p1) {
    const r = 6371;
    let d, dLat, dLon;

    const lat2 = p2[1][0];
    const lon2 = p2[1][1];
    const lat1 = p1[1][0];
    const lon1 = p1[1][1];

    dLat = lat2 - lat1;
    dLon = lon2 - lon1;

    let a =
        Math.sin(dLat / 2) ** 2 +
        Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) ** 2;
    let c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    d = r * c;

    return d; // distance in km
};


const calcDirectRoute = function(input) {

    let tripList = [];
    let distances = [];
    let tempStart = input[0];



    // we need to loop over twince but skip same index (city)
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
            if (i == j) {
                continue;
            } // if start and ending index is same skip
            let start = input[i];
            let end = input[j];
            //below line is  distances.push([start[0],start[1],end[0],end[1], calcDist2Points(start, end)]);
            distances.push([...start, ...end, calcDist2Points(start, end)]);
        }
    }

    return distances;
}


const getShortestPath = () => {
    // every city distance from one another cityGraph[0] = [...city1, ...city2 , distance]
    let cityGraph = calcDirectRoute(world)
    let nodes = cityGraph.map((arr) => {
        return {
            start: arr[0][0],
            end: arr[2][0],
            distance: arr[4]
        };
    });

    let leafArr = [];
    let createTree = (city, visited, distance) => {
        let pn = nodes.filter(n => n.start === city && !visited.some(v => v === n.end));
        if (pn.length === 0) {
            leafArr.push({
                path: [...visited, city],
                distance: distance
            })

        }

        pn.forEach(n => createTree(n.end, [...visited, city], distance + n.distance));
    }

    createTree(nodes[0].start, [], 0);

    // {  path: [ 'Start', 'Toronto', 'Moscow', 'London', 'NY' ],  distance: 26711.477438060127  }
    let shortestLeaf = leafArr.reduce((prev, curr) => prev.distance < curr.distance ? prev : curr);


    let distacesPath = [];
    shortestLeaf.path.reduce((pre, next) => {
        let dis = cityGraph.find(c => c[0][0] === pre && c[2][0] === next);
        distacesPath.push(dis)
        return next;
    });

    return distacesPath;
}

console.log(getShortestPath());
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think you got my question right. I need an array that would comprise a FULL trip from Start to the remaining cities, and you only output a result for NY-London trip, for some reason. It needs to start from Start >> Toronto, then Toronto >> London, then London >> etc BASED on the shortest distance for the following destination

Comment: @chessplayer so you are basically asking for pattern where we start  from 'start' and cover all the cities with lowest possible total distance travelled.

Comment: @chessplayer or do you want that 'start' should travel to the closest city and then again to the closest city but not caring about total distance.

Comment: The former sentence you mentioned! The distance should also be covered, as I will need to make some operations with it after

Comment: This is not an easy solution, you need to use Dijkstra's algorithm and merge it with your code

Comment: @chessplayer I have attached a working example, might not be very optimized but should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to update a little your `calcDist2Points()` function.
also I updated the way `world` object is defined.

The distance attribute represent the distance to the previous city.

I am sure I could improve to make it simpler using 3rd libraries. for now I believe is functional.

and I am including a implementation using ramda [here](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.27.0#?%2F%2F%20import%20%7B%20dissoc%2C%20head%2C%20isEmpty%2C%20reduce%20%7D%20from%20%22ramda%22%3B%0A%0Aconst%20compareByDistance%20%3D%20%28%7B%20distance%3A%20distA%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20distance%3A%20distB%20%7D%29%20%3D%3E%20distA%20-%20distB%3B%0A%0Aconst%20getDistances%20%3D%20%28originCoordinates%2C%20cities%29%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20Object.entries%28cities%29%0A%20%20%20%20.map%28%28%5Bcity%2C%20coordinates%5D%29%20%3D%3E%20%28%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20city%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20coordinates%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20distance%3A%20calcDist2Points%28originCoordinates%2C%20coordinates%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20.sort%28compareByDistance%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20formatOutput%20%3D%20reduce%28%0A%20%20%28%7B%20last%2C%20result%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20name%2C%20coordinates%2C%20distance%20%7D%29%20%3D%3E%20%28%7B%0A%20%20%20%20last%3A%20%7B%20name%2C%20coordinates%2C%20distance%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20result%3A%20isEmpty%28last%29%20%3F%20result%20%3A%20%5B...result%2C%20%5B%5Blast.name%5D%2C%20last.coordinates%2C%20%5Bname%5D%2C%20coordinates%2C%20distance%5D%5D%2C%0A%20%20%7D%29%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20last%3A%20%7B%7D%2C%20result%3A%20%5B%5D%20%7D%0A%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20formatEntry%20%3D%20reduce%28%28cities%2C%20%5B%5Bname%5D%2C%20coordinates%5D%29%20%3D%3E%20%28%7B%20...cities%2C%20%5Bname%5D%3A%20coordinates%20%7D%29%2C%20%7B%7D%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20world%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%5B%5B%22Start%22%5D%2C%20%5B20%2C%2020%5D%5D%2C%0A%20%20%5B%5B%22NY%22%5D%2C%20%5B29%2C%2030%5D%5D%2C%0A%20%20%5B%5B%22London%22%5D%2C%20%5B24%2C%2027%5D%5D%2C%0A%20%20%5B%5B%22Moscow%22%5D%2C%20%5B29%2C%2032%5D%5D%2C%0A%20%20%5B%5B%22Toronto%22%5D%2C%20%5B20%2C%2023%5D%5D%2C%0A%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20calcDist2Points%20%3D%20function%20%28p2%2C%20p1%29%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20r%20%3D%206371%3B%0A%20%20let%20d%2C%20dLat%2C%20dLon%3B%0A%0A%20%20const%20lat2%20%3D%20p2%5B0%5D%3B%0A%20%20const%20lon2%20%3D%20p2%5B1%5D%3B%0A%20%20const%20lat1%20%3D%20p1%5B0%5D%3B%0A%20%20const%20lon1%20%3D%20p1%5B1%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20dLat%20%3D%20lat2%20-%20lat1%3B%0A%20%20dLon%20%3D%20lon2%20-%20lon1%3B%0A%0A%20%20let%20a%20%3D%20Math.sin%28dLat%20%2F%202%29%20%2A%2A%202%20%2B%20Math.cos%28lat1%29%20%2A%20Math.cos%28lat2%29%20%2A%20Math.sin%28dLon%20%2F%202%29%20%2A%2A%202%3B%0A%20%20let%20c%20%3D%202%20%2A%20Math.atan2%28Math.sqrt%28a%29%2C%20Math.sqrt%281%20-%20a%29%29%3B%0A%20%20d%20%3D%20r%20%2A%20c%3B%0A%0A%20%20return%20d%3B%20%2F%2F%20distance%20in%20km%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20calcDirectRoute%20%3D%20%28cities%2C%20trip%2C%20origin%29%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20isEmpty%28cities%29%0A%20%20%20%20%3F%20trip%0A%20%20%20%20%3A%20%28%28closest%29%20%3D%3E%20calcDirectRoute%28dissoc%28closest.name%2C%20cities%29%2C%20%5B...trip%2C%20closest%5D%2C%20closest%29%29%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20head%28getDistances%28origin.coordinates%2C%20cities%29%29%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20res%20%3D%20calcDirectRoute%28formatEntry%28world%29%2C%20%5B%5D%2C%20%7B%20coordinates%3A%20%5B20%2C%2020%5D%20%7D%29%3B%0Aconst%20%7B%20result%20%7D%20%3D%20formatOutput%28res%29%3B%0A%0Aresult)

```js
const formatOutput = (tripList) =>
  tripList.reduce((acc, { name, coordinates, distance }, index, arr) => {
    if (index <= 0) return [];
    const { name: prevName, coordinates: prevCoordinates } = arr[index - 1];
    const obj = [[prevName], prevCoordinates, [name], [...coordinates], distance];
    return [...acc, obj];
  }, []);

const compareByDistance = ({ distance: distanceA }, { distance: distanceB }) => distanceA - distanceB;

const getDistances = (origin, cities) =>
  Object.entries(cities)
    .map(([city, coordinates]) => ({ name: city, coordinates, distance: calcDist2Points(origin, coordinates) }))
    .sort(compareByDistance);

const world = [
  [["Start"], [20, 20]],
  [["NY"], [29, 30]],
  [["London"], [24, 27]],
  [["Moscow"], [29, 32]],
  [["Toronto"], [20, 23]],
];

const calcDist2Points = function (p2, p1) {
  const r = 6371;
  let d, dLat, dLon;

  const lat2 = p2[0];
  const lon2 = p2[1];
  const lat1 = p1[0];
  const lon1 = p1[1];

  dLat = lat2 - lat1;
  dLon = lon2 - lon1;

  let a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) ** 2 + Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) ** 2;
  let c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
  d = r * c;

  return d; // distance in km
};

const calcDirectRoute = function (start, input) {
  const cities = input.reduce((cities, [[name], coordinates]) => ({ ...cities, [name]: coordinates }), []);
  const tripList = [];
  let coordinates = cities[start];

  do {
    const [closest] = getDistances(coordinates, cities);
    delete cities[closest.name];
    coordinates = closest.coordinates;
    tripList.push(closest);
  } while (Object.keys(cities).length !== 0);

  return formatOutput(tripList);
};

console.log(calcDirectRoute("Start", world));
```